# Why does cv::circle() only display on a 3D matrix for certain RGB values?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm seeing some weird behaviour that I wasn't expecting.  On a pure white matrix of type `CV_64FC3` (3 channels, floating point values), I'm drawing a coloured circle.  The unexpected behaviour is that the circle only actually displays for certain RGB values.  Here is sample output for my program for two different colours:

[image: printing a red circle]

[image: printing a gray circle]

Clearly, the gray circle is missing.  My question: Why? And how can I make it appear?  Below is my sample code in a small program that you can run.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

void main()
{
    const unsigned int diam = 200;
    cv::namedWindow("test_window");
    cv::Mat mat(diam, diam, CV_64FC3);

    // force assignment of each pixel to white.
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < diam; ++row)
    {
        for (unsigned col = 0; col < diam; ++col)
        {
            mat.at<cv::Vec3d>(row, col)[0] = 255;
            mat.at<cv::Vec3d>(row, col)[1] = 255;
            mat.at<cv::Vec3d>(row, col)[2] = 255;
        }
    }

    // big gray circle.
    cv::circle(mat, cv::Point(diam/2, diam/2), (diam/2) - 5, CV_RGB(169, 169, 169), -1, CV_AA);

    cv::imshow("test_window", mat);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried another datatype for your Mat? (Like CV_32FC3 or an integer type) Not sure if that would make a difference but it might be another clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using float matrix type. From opencv [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/user_interface.html#cv-imshow):

> If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied
>   by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

Here is the working code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void main()
{
    const unsigned int diam = 200;
    cv::namedWindow("test_window");
    // force assignment of each pixel to white.
    cv::Mat3b mat = cv::Mat3b(diam, diam, cv::Vec3b(255,255,255));

    // big gray circle.
    cv::circle(mat, cv::Point(diam/2, diam/2), (diam/2) - 5, CV_RGB(169, 169, 169), -1, CV_AA);

    cv::imshow("test_window", mat);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

upd.

1. Do not use loops for matrices filling. Mat::zeros(), Mat::ones() and constructor from example above looks much better.U
2. Use special cv::MatXY types to prevent runtime errors with wrong types.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why OP's code didn't work in it's original form.

Comment: @bde, "the pixel values are multiplied by 255" - this means any non-zero value was multiplied to be out of range. The red color had 2 zero components while the gray had none and thus turned to white.

Comment: @Mark, thanks, that makes sense. I just wanted to make sure the cause of the problem was included here somewhere.

Comment: Interesting reasoning!  In this scenario, the suggested data type would be unsigned character then, right?  If you wanted values between 0 and 255, that makes sense to me.

Comment: Very good second remark at the end! One seldom writes really general algorithms anyway, but ones which only work with a particular Mat, +1.